# Django inlineformset_factory rendering throwing error

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to build a view with 2 models using inlinefactory.

**Models.py**

```
class serviceinvoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='invoice')    
    invoice_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = increment_invoice_number, null = True, blank = True)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    invoice_receivable=models.ForeignKey(Receivables,null=True)
    total_amount=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    total_amountwithtax=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number

class serviceinvoiceitems(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='serviceinvoiceitems')
    invoice_number=models.ForeignKey(serviceinvoice)
    Product=models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    UOM=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Quantity=models.FloatField(null=True)
    Rate=models.FloatField(null=True)
    Tax_rate=models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number
```

**forms.py**

```
createinvoiceformset = inlineformset_factory(serviceinvoice, serviceinvoiceitems,fields='__all__')

class createinvoice(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = serviceinvoice
        exclude = ('user',)
        widgets = {
            'invoice_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def createinvoice(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        inv_form=createinvoice(data=request.POST)        
        if inv_form.is_valid():
            new_form=inv_form.save(commit=False)
            new_formset=createinvoiceformset(request.POST,instance=new_form)
            if new_formset.is_valid():
                new_form.save()
                new_formset.save()
                return HttpResponse('Invoice created')
    else:
        inv_form=createinvoice()
        new_formset=createinvoiceformset(instance=serviceinvoice())
        inv_form.fields["invoice_receivable"].queryset=Receivables.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'account/createinvoice.html',{'inv_form':inv_form,'new_formset':new_formset})
```

This is rendered in template with following error.

> _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/invoice/createinvoice/

Django Version: 1.8.9
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('invoice',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\pythonspace\tiktant\invoice\views.py" in createinvoice
  106.         inv_form=createinvoice(instance=request)

Exception Type: TypeError at /invoice/createinvoice/
Exception Value: _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: Please show the complete traceback when posting questions.

Comment: @Alasdair Your answer did wonder but at form submission getting error "local variable 'new_formset' referenced before assignment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view name `createinvoice` clashes with your form `createinvoice`. They should be different.

Your code would be much clearer if you used underscores for function names (e.g. `def create_invoice(...)`), and CamelCase for class names (e.g. `class CreateInvoice(...)`, `CreateInvoiceFormSet`, ...)

Comment: It worked. But while submitting the form, i get error "local variable 'new_formset' referenced before assignment" . Any solution, please

Comment: The problem is that you are not defining `new_formset` when the request method is `POST` but the form is not valid. You could fix it by moving `new_formset=createinvoiceformset(instance=serviceinvoice())` to the top of the view.

Comment: Note that you are only changing the `invoice_receivable` queryset for GET requests. That means that users might be able to tamper with the POST request and choose a different `invoice_receivable`.

Comment: New to django. `invoice_receivable` field is hidden, user cannot view it. May be i dont know how to do it!!!

Comment: It worked but now 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'

Comment: Hiding a form input doesn't stop users from editing it.

Comment: You have probably forgotten to [include the management form in your template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates), e.g. `{{ new_formset.management_form }}`. These are separate issues, we have solved your original question. If you still have errors please ask a new question.

Comment: Please be online, seems django god. Putting it write now.

Comment: Maybe take a break then ;)

Comment: Posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725912/inlineformset-validation-error-list-object-has-no-attribute-user